# What is the best language to write network tools in

Tags: sockets, networking, ssh

What language can you recommend (and why) for making networking tools:

- network analyzer (packet sniffing)
- speedtest (sending traffic, calculating the total speed and involving QoS analyses)
- network monitor (promiscious mode network listener)
- SSH client (with own extensions)

I'm thinking about: Java, C# or C++ (reason: Object oriented, found some standard functions in the language itself without having to import existing api's)

The purpose is to learn to write such apps without the use of API's.

Comment: Neither of those. What you're asking for is pretty low level. Personally, I'd go for C. Very subjective.

Comment: Off course it's a bit subjective, the point of this question is to make a decision based on multiple opinions. It bothers me that C# doesn't have a proper SSH lib built in so that's one of the reason's why C# is lower on my personal list.

Comment: I don't want to be blind for better languages to suit my purpose then those that I already know. Hence the question, I seek other opinions (and possibilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an unmanaged language for the sensitive parts of the apps.  Anything where latency and absolute performance are an issue.  I'd use Java or a managed .Net language for everything else.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking about C (or c++) to do the networking-part and give it a C# windows GUI to show the results. Can C(++) do some basic networking, ssh for example, without the use of any third API's (like sharpssh in C#), with the exception of the encryption and protocol dependencies? Thank you for your help btw!

Comment: Sure, it's just a protocol.  The effort seems like it's overkill.  Why not build on something that exists?

Comment: I want to be able to make my own networking tools later and for me it's more a matter of learning then really using the program in the futur (sure if I'm satisfied, I will, but it's not my main goal). I've already done programming with databases and information processing but now I really want to make some networking programs. I've set my goal, now I need to gather information and prepare myself to do it... .

Comment: Nice.  Good Luck and have fun!